# Is there such a method that computes 'e' to 'n' correct digits with less than 'n' iterations?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, approximation, decimal-expansion, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have been looking into methods and formulae that yields approximations of 'e', one thing i have observed is that at least the ones i have tried tend to use by far more iterations than the number of correct digits they generate.

Is there no method that has a better convergence as well as less time needed to generate correct digits than them?.

Comment: While the answer is undoubtedly included in the answers of the possible duplicate, it would be nice if an answer is posted here giving explicitly the run-time asymptotics for computing the $n$th digit. As far as I can tell this was not given in the previous question/answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power series expansion
$$ \mathrm{e}^x = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!} x^2 + \frac{1}{3!} x^3 + \cdots + \frac{1}{k!} x^k + \cdots  $$
converges quite quickly.  Set $x=1$ and you are just summing reciprocal factorials.  The sum of the first $n$ terms, $s_n$, satisfies
$$ s_n < \mathrm{e} < s_n + \frac{1}{n \cdot n!}  $$
so is certainly gaining a digit of precision after $10$ terms, two digits each after $100$ terms, and so on.  (Euler actually used this method to find $23$ decimal digits of his constant (that is, $23$ digits after the decimal).  See  L. Euler, [Introduction à l'analyse infinitésimale](http://eulerarchive.maa.org//docs/other/e101french.pdf) (French translation by Labey), Barrois, ainé, Librairie, (original 1748, translation 1796), vol. 1, p. 89-90.  In fact, page 89, just three lines above the marginal notation "(q)".  As an amusing coincidence, this can be obtained after just $23$ terms.)

Binary splitting can be used to improve the running time of an implementation of this series method.  See Xavier Gourdon and Pascal Sebah, [Binary splitting method](http://www.brotherstechnology.com/docs/binarysplit.pdf), 2001.  This is usually overcomplex for "small" number of digits, but can be effective for thousands or millions (or more) of digits.

Comment: I have read about the use of e power series and binary splitting method here http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/e-500b.html .
Is this one the best method to this day?

Comment: I also see that the taylor series of e was used for the current e computation world record (5,000,000,000,000 digits!)
http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/records.html
Information
http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/records/2016_8_28_e.txt

Comment: Since the factorials increase so quickly, the number of digits of precision increases quickly as well.  As $100! \gt 10^{157}$ we would expect (absent magical cancellation) there to be at least $157$ correct decimals after $100$ terms.

Comment: @RossMillikan : ... and, as I mentioned, is gaining (at least) two correct digits per term at $100!$ ...

Comment: For a medium-size number of bits (few hundreds to few thousands), the following will often be faster than using the power series for $e^x$ without adding much complexity: $t = \sinh x = x + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + ...$ then $\exp x = t + \sqrt{1 + t^2}$, where the square root can be computed via the Halley iteration for the reciprocal square root (cubic convergence).